# GIF decoding sends memory warnings then kills the app

Tags: ios, crash, uiimage, out-of-memory

When decoding certain gifs my app receives 2-3 memory warnings then gets killed by iOS.
The gif size is only 200kb, it should be fine to decode.

Seems every gif created using adobe flash has the same issue

I've created an example project here: 
https://github.com/amleszk/GifBlocking

Runnign on simulator will work fine. running on device will crash with low memory. The bundled gif file "rXYyQTo.gif" is the only one that crashes

I've been trying to fix this for days, suspect its just a bug in ImageIO framework

Comment: If you believe this is a bug, please report a bug via [Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn)

Comment: Have you profiled with instruments?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are decompressing images on memory. The file size isn't the main factor when you decompress an image, the real memory is :
`numberOfPixelInHeight*numberOfPixelInWidth*numberOfByte`
`numberOfByte` is about the number of  bit for each channel, like RGBA image with 8bit ( one byte) for each channel means 1*4=4 bytes. 
GIF doesn't have alpha an probably also less bit for each channel, but you decompress each frame so you should add another moltiplication factor: `numberOfFrames`.
I would suggest you to save each frame on a temp dir.